# timestamp convertion in java (windows 128 bit System structure to human readable format

Tags: java, android

i want to convert windows :128 bit system structure ie.., "D9070B00010002000600090013000000"
to human readable format ie.., Mon, 02 November 2009 06:09:19 so there is algorithm to convert it which i am not getting. for refference http://www.digital-detective.co.uk/freetools/decode.asp where the example time and converted time in java.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The format you included is some sort of little-endian hex-encoded mess of WORDs. Looks horribly inefficient.

But, it could be decoded like this:

```
long getSystemStructureTime(String enc) {
    long result = -1L;
    // system time is typically a set of WORDs encoded, little-endian
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(enc)) {
        final int length = enc.length();
        ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(length / 2);
        b.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
        for (int i = 0; i < enc.length(); i+=2) {
            b.put((byte) Integer.parseInt(enc.substring(i, i + 2), 16));
        }
        b.flip();
        b.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
        try {
            int year = b.getShort();
            int month = b.getShort();
            int day = b.getShort();
            int dayOfMonth = b.getShort();
            int hourOfDay = b.getShort();
            int minuteOfHour = b.getShort();
            int secondsOfMinute = b.getShort();
            int millisOfSecond = b.getShort();

            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month - 1); // months in calendar are base 0
            c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuteOfHour);
            c.set(Calendar.SECOND, secondsOfMinute);
            c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, millisOfSecond);

            result = c.getTimeInMillis();
        } catch (BufferUnderflowException e) {
            // This wasn't a proper time..
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Cramming in what you posted:

```
System.out.println(new Date(getSystemStructureTime("D9070B00010002000600090013000000")));
```

yields:

```
Mon Nov 02 06:09:19 GMT+00:00 2009
```

This version returns the time in milliseconds, it might be better to return the `Calendar` instance created during the parsing, depending on what you like.

Comment: thank you so much for the support this is working fine for me thank a lot i am searching for this logic from past 3 days. I am also looking to convert msdos date and time to readable format 3561A436 to Fri, 04 May 2007 12:09:42  Local thanks in advance

Comment: Just incase other people need conversion. Looks like it is RFC-4122.