# Convert REG_BINARY 128-bit to a datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, registry

I'm trying to work out in C# how to convert a REG_BINARY 128-bit value to date and time. I know I can use Bitconverter for 64-bit values but that doesn't work for 128-bit.

The registry value is E5070A000500080012000D0018002703. I can use DCode with the Decode Format: Windows: 128 bit SYSTEM structure to get the date and time but want to know how to do this is C#. Can anyone help me please?

[image: Dcode example]

Comment: Does this help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10496861/timestamp-convertion-in-java-windows-128-bit-system-structure-to-human-readable?force_isolation=true

Comment: Thanks @jdweng. I think it does! I used that to write the answer below. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
private static DateTime GetDateFrom128Byte(byte[] binary)
{
    if (binary == null || binary.Length != 16)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    return new DateTime(binary[0] + binary[1] * 256, binary[2], binary[6], binary[8], binary[10], 0);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).